# Canon MX320 printer connected to Windows 10 and shared over network but cannot be used from Mac

Tags: mac, network, printing, sharing

I'm running Monterey on my Mac and there are no drivers for my Canon MX320. To get around this, I've connected the printer to my Windows 10 computer and shared it over the network. I was able to add it as a printer on my Mac without issue, but it won't actually print. I always get a "Hold for authentication" message and so far all the solutions for similar problems I've found on the internet do not work.

[image: Printer Settings on Windows]

[image: Network Sharing Settings on Windows]

[image: Printer Configuration on Mac]

[image: Printer Successful added to Mac]

[image: Hold for authentication message]